# How to get the Sum of specific property using dynamic query

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, dynamic-linq

How to use Sum in dynamic linq query.

I have the following datasource :

```
List<Excuse> li = new List<Excuse>();
li.Add(new Excuse { EmpNum = 3333, ExcuseDate = DateTime.Today, ExcuseDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), ExcuseType = 0, Id = 1 });
li.Add(new Excuse { EmpNum = 3333, ExcuseDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), ExcuseDuration = new TimeSpan(2, 30, 0), ExcuseType = 0, Id = 2 });
li.Add(new Excuse { EmpNum = 3333, ExcuseDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2), ExcuseDuration = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0), ExcuseType = 0, Id = 3 });
li.Add(new Excuse { EmpNum = 2345, ExcuseDate = DateTime.Now, ExcuseDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), ExcuseType = 0, Id = 4});
```

---

> I want to get summation of `ExcuseDuration` for specific `emp_num` in
>   the same month of the year.

---

something like

```
var langExp2 = "YEAR(ExcuseDate) = @1 AND MONTH(ExcuseDate) = @2 AND emp_num = @3";
var query1 = li.AsQueryable().Where(langExp2, 2019,5,3333)
```

Now I want to get the sum of `ExcuseDuration`?

Comment: please use `Database.SqlQuery`

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or really just a local list? Do you really need to use dynamic Linq or will standard Linq be OK?

Comment: @DavidG: I have two applications,the first one should allow the user(Admin) to build `rules` and I want the rules to be saved in the database so I used dynamic queries so that the other applications who use these rules can use the rules directly and dynamically.

Comment: That answers neither of my questions, but it really looks like your question is becoming too broad to be answered here.

Comment: @DavidG `Are you using Entity Framework or really just a local list?` the list will be passed to my function so it's a local list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```cs
long result = (long) li.AsQueryable().Where("EmpNum = @0", 3333).Select("it.ExcuseDuration.Ticks").Sum();
var totalDuration = new TimeSpan(result);
```